# What is the correct way to set state of a nested objects in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

This code snippet replicates my problem from the piece of software that i am currently working on in this X company.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      some:{
        name:"axys",
        a:[1,2.23,46,612,5],
        z:{
          a:2,
          b:5,
          c:6,
        }
      }
    };
  }

handler = () =>{
  console.log(this.state);
  this.setState({
    some:{
      z:{
        a:1111
      }
    }
  },()=>{
    console.log(this.state);
  })
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <button onClick = {this.handler}>
          Change State
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Lets say i want to change the value of this.state.some.z.a, what i though initially was

```
this.setState({
    some:{
      z:{
        a:1111
      }
    }
}
```

But It turns out the state returned to me is

```
{
  "name": "React",
  "some": {
    "z": {
      "a": 1111
    }
  }
}
```

So to get the intended output I need to write

```
this.setState({
    some:{
      ...this.state.some,
      z:{
        ...this.state.some.z,
        a:1111
      }
    }
  }
```

So my question is, is this the correct/recommended way of doing things or am I missing something.

If this is the correct way, won't the performance of setState dependent on Spread Operator (...)?

Comment: *is this the correct/recommended way?* I guess Yes.

Comment: It's ONE correct way to do it. You could also use deep clone function (like from lodash or rolling your own) to clone it first, change a single prop then reload entire object into state. But essentially yes, you can't change a single nested value in react state without creating a new instance of the whole object. And remember spread operator doesn't do deep copies: https://bambielli.com/til/2017-01-29-spread-operator-deep-copy/#

Comment: Your code remove all the other except `this.state.some.z.a`. Do you want to have them or the output of your code is fine to you?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do what you are trying to do, as others have mentioned. But the *correct* way to do the specific way you mentioned is to use `prevState`, since `this.state` is unreliable (because it is asynchronous).

Here is a working examples:

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
  some: {
    ...prevState.some,
    z: {
      ...prevState.some.z,
      a: 1111
    }
  }
}))
```

> Great explanation: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/react-docs-now-recommends-using-function-with-prevstate-inside-of-setstate

Answer (score 0):

```
there are two ways to do it 

1. copy the object into some:

    handler = () => {
        let some = Object.assign({}, this.state.some);
        some.z.a = 1111;
        this.setState({ some }, () => {
          console.log(this.state);
        });
      };

will give an output:

    {
    name: "React"
    some: Object
    name: "axys"
    a: Array[5]
    z: Object
    a: 1111
    b: 5
    c: 6}

2. using the spead oprator
    handler = () => {
        let some = { ...this.state.some };
        console.log(some)
        this.setState(
          prevstate => ({
            some: {
             z:{ ...prevstate.some.z,
              a: 1111}
            }
          }),
          () => {
            console.log(this.state);
          }
        );
      };

with solution:

    {name: "React"
    some: Object
    z: Object
    a: 1111
    b: 5
    c: 6}
hope it will help
```